# How to compare textbox value with table cell value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this table which displays values of product name and available stock  retrieving from database. I want to insert quantity manually.

The code contains php incremental id's for table row, available stock cell and quantity textbox, such as `last_<?php echo $id; ?>` for stock and  `quanti_<?php echo $id; ?>` for quantity.

I want to compare these two values such as quantity value must be less than or equal to stock `value.onclick` of generate bill button we again want to validate for not to submit form if quantity is greater than stock.

```
$(".edit_td1").click(function()
{
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    //alert(ID);
    //$('#quanti_'+ID).blur(function(){
    $('.cls_quant').blur(function(){
        //var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        //var qt=$('#quanti_'+ID).val();
        var qt=$(this).val();
        var stk=$('#last_'+ID).html();

        console.log("Quanty"+qt);
        console.log("Stock"+stk);

        if (qt>stk)
        {
            console.log("Quantity > than stock");
            return false;
        }
        else

            return true;

    });
});
```

Comment: All values displayed correctly on console?

Comment: Show us your html also or make an online demo of your code.

Comment: Here you are attaching two events e.g. *click* and *blur*. So you need to be sure that you can use only one jquery event at a time for above case.

You can *traverse* selector to '.cls_quant' input and resolve your problem your self. If you want a help then please paste your HTML Here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add parseInt() fucntion to your vars like that:

```
var qt = parseInt($(this).val());
var stk= parseInt($('#last_'+ID).html());
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This works good for for first row but if we blur and goes to second textbox it takes stk value as first rows stk values....

Answer (score 0):

If the value displayed correctly just parsed into number like so :

```
var qt   =  +$(this).val();
var stk  =  +$('#last_'+ID).html();
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it works for first <tr> only

Comment: Yes of course because you use `ID`, this will return fisrt matched element only, another rest it won't. Change all repetition element that use and ID into class definition. And share your HTML code together. Wanna see that.